# Keyboard module multiple if

Tags: python, keyboard

```py
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "up":
        print("up")
    if keyboard.read_key() == "down":
        print("down")
    if keyboard.read_key() == "enter":
        print("enter")
```

Sometimes the print function only run after second key press.

Python 3.11

I literally tried every other module and every possible if-elif-while combination.

Comment: Try saving `keyboard.read_key()` as a variable, then running your if statements using that variable. Currently, you could be missing a down key because when it happens, you poll for it and only check to see if it is an up key. Then when you check for a down key afterwards, the moment has passed.

Comment: You're calling `read_key()` three times.  Each of those `if` statements reads a fresh keypress.

Comment: Presumably you meant to call `read_key()` just once, and compare that key to up/down/enter.

Comment: @MillerTime I tried, this solution makes every output double

Answer (score 0):

To make the code a bit cleaner, you can consider using a `dictionary` with messages:

```
import keyboard
message  =  {"up": "up", "down": "down", "enter": "enter"}
while True:
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    
    if key in message:
        print(message[key])
        while keyboard.is_pressed(key): pass
```

If you have a lot of messages for different keys, using a `dictionary` could be faster as well.

---

@Sedus Just for clarity, discovered that the order of the commands had to be changed to avoid double key presses

```
        while keyboard.is_pressed(key): pass
        print(message[key])
```

Comment: same double output

Comment: I do not understand either this double print output thing

Comment: I added a new line of code. Please try again, does it work? `while keyboard.is_pressed(key): pass`

Comment: better, now its 50-50 for double or single output

Comment: I added a new method. This one should really work. Please let me know if the problem still appears.

Comment: Thanks, I could resolve using your `while keyboard.is_pressed(key): pass` solution

Comment: Nice, the order of the commands had to be changed.